# block commits of codes with secrets or passwords

Tags: git, github, github-api

Looking for a solution for blocking the developers from committing the codes or any files with password or secretes in it.

We are using GitHub Enterprise

Looking for some kind of pre-commit hook script , which should block the users for commiting codes/files or any kind of secretes/keys/passwords init.

Regards!!

Comment: Github has webhooks that are invoked by certain events, including `push`. See https://developer.github.com/webhooks/.

Comment: You could block the files by adding them to the `.gitignore` file. If the file is already in your source control you can unlist it with: `git rm --cached yoursecretfile.txt` If you omit the --cached the file will also be deleted from the working tree

Comment: What if "this is not a secret" is your secret? :-)

Comment: yes, correct, so need a solution where it should filter entire file with some keywords like username or password, or key, or such all kind of things..

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a specific file or file extension, Baklap4's comment about adding to the .gitignore is definitely the way to go.

If you are talking about searching for passwords, secrets, or keys in *any* file, that's much more of a challenge. It's going to be really difficult to determine what is and isn't a password/secret/key programmatically. In a easy scenario, your passwords/secrets/keys have a "standard" that they follow and you can try to create a regular expression that finds them. If not, that's probably impossible. Suppose another developer created a variable named bestVariableEver. What if that's my Windows login? How is it supposed to know.

Comment: yes Mike, You are correct.  But need a solution for atleast block the codes/ config files with keywords of password portion.. for example, keyword: - password, sshkey, aws key... etc.... Once that is implemented, we can extend that with more other scenario wise. But  I am stuck here to how to achieve this... organisation level and account level of repositories in github